# How can I take value of the field from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new to `Node.js`. I have a collection with four documents. All documents have three fields "_id", "num" and "str".
I send the result on the page of browser

```
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
 hwUsers.aggregate(pipeline)
    .then((hwu) => {
        res.send(hwu);})
    .catch((err) => {
        res.send(err)});
});
```

This is my pipeline:

```
let pipeline = [{
    "$match": {num: 1}
    },
    {
    "$project":{str: 1, _id: 0}
}];
```

This is result which i see on the page
[{"str":"lo "}]
My question is next.
How can I take just value from field, if I can of course.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the document(object) from your collection.The aggregation always returns an object or array of objects. So if you want to get the value you can type something like this:`res.send(hwu.map(item=>{ return item.str }))`
And you will get the array of values.

Comment: Thank you very mach, I am happy. It works.